# Why the geometric series of a random variable that takes all $\mathbb Z$ numbers include $p_{0}$+constant?

Tags: geometric-progressions

As I don't have at least 10 reputation so I cannot post formulates made by another web page like codecogs.

My question is that I need to calculate the geometric progression of (you can post this codeon codecogs and see what Im trying to ask)

$$  p_{k}=\frac{1}{3}\times 2^{-\begin{vmatrix} k \end{vmatrix}}$$

Where $k$ takes all integers numbers $\mathbb Z$.

The answer is

$$  \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}^{\infty }p_k=p_{0}+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }p_{k}=\frac{1}{3}+2\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty }p_{k}=\frac{1}{3}+2\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=1 $$

Why do I have at the beginning and the answer

$$ p_{0}+2 $$

And the total answer it's not only

$$   \frac{1}{3}\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you can't post formulas yet, then just learn mathjax ;) Anyway, the third sum should have $2^{-k}$ instead of $p_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how the sum is taken over all integers, not just $\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$ as usual. Note also that $p_k = p_{-k}$ because of the definition. Therefore:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty p_k 
&= p_0 + (p_{-1} + p_{-2} + \cdots) + (p_1 + p_2 + \cdots) \\
&= p_0 + (p_{1} + p_{2} + \cdots) + (p_1 + p_2 + \cdots) \\ \\
&= p_0 + 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k
\end{align}
$$

Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So as pk=p-k, (p-1 + p-2 + p+3...) turn (p1 + p2 + p3..) and p0 = 1/3 its because k = 0 ? Another question is, why pk = p-k, where can I have an easy reading about it? Thanks.

Comment: $p_0 = \frac13 2^{-|0|} =  \frac13$. $p_{-k} = \frac13 2^{-|-k|} = \frac13 2^{-|k|} = p_k$. $p_{-k} = p_k$ only because of the definition of $p_k$ (it is an even function of $k$).